# Magento 2 - How use join between sales_order and sales_order_item table

Tags: magento2, sales-order, join

How to use Join in Magento2. i want to get `customer_firstname` from `sales_order` table and `price` , `qty_ordered` columns from `sales_order_item` table where `sales_order.entity_id=sales_order_item.order_id`
Kindly guide me it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below script. It will help you definitely.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$connection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $conn = $connection->getConnection();
    $select = $conn->select()
        ->from(
            ['main_table' => 'sales_order'],
            [
                'main_table.customer_firstname',
                'sales_item.price',
                'sales_item.qty_ordered'
            ]
        )
        ->join(
            ['sales_item' => 'sales_order_item'],
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_item.order_id'
        )->order('fieldname','DESC');

$data = $conn->fetchAll($select);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data); die;
```

Comment: can we setOrder in this collection ? like $conn->fetchAll($select)->setOrder('feildname','DESC') ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Check I have updated my answer.

Comment: is not work `->order('fieldname','DESC');`

Comment: It's working I have checked. if there are two fields with the same name, you can you alias like, main_table.fieldname

Answer (score 1):

You are joining `sales_order` and `sales_order_item` table correctly also add `sales_order_item.base_row_total > 0` or `sales_order_item.base_price > 0` in your where clause because in configurable product case it give you two rows one for configurable and other for simple item. So it will be good if you want to fetch single row against each product Id.

**I hope this will help**